# how can I get unix to list number of lines in a file and just output the file name?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I am new to unix and was kind of stuck with the below, could you let me know how I can do this?

List    the number  of  lines   in  the files   in

```
/courses/projweek/unix/commands/quotes, sorted  by
```

the number  of  lines   they    contain,    so  it  looks   like    this:

```
 2 deadlines.txt
 2 live.txt
 3 airports.txt
 3 universe.txt
 6 universe2.txt
```

How would   you make    that    list    contain just    the file    names?  e.g.    like    this:

```
deadlines.txt
live.txt
airports.txt
universe.txt
universe2.txt
```

Comment: With the `cut` command.

Comment: looks like homework? Look into `cut` `sort` and `wc`

Comment: @kchoose2 it isn't homework it a worksheet used to improve unix skills for beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `find`,`wc` and `sort` like below to achieve first part -

```
find /courses/projweek/unix/commands/quotes -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sort -n
```

and second part you can achieve using below command

```
find /courses/projweek/unix/commands/quotes -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sort -n | cut -d "/" -f2
```

Comment: Almost. Your first command will include the whole path, not just the file name, and your second command won't keep the sorting of the first command. It will try to numerically sort the file names by their paths.

Comment: The first one i used wc -l *.txt

Comment: @kchoose2 thanks for suggesting the correction, I didn't notice in second part we need to preserve the sorting in first part. will update my answer for second part